# If product of two ideals is regular

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity . An ideal $I$ of $R$ is called a regular ideal if $I$ contains an element which is not a zero-divisor .

Now if $I,J$ are regular ideals of $R$ then definitely $IJ$ is a regular ideal of $R$ .

My question is , is the converse true : If $I,J$ are ideals of $R$ such that $IJ$ is a regular ideal , then are $I,J$ regular ideals ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $I$ is not regular.

Then all elements of $I$ are zero divisors, hence, since $IJ \subseteq I$, so are all elements of $IJ$.

It follows that if $IJ$ is regular, then $I,J$ are both regular.